# Is it possible to incorporate Queries into a case structure?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So, What I would like to do is create a flag based on multiple attributes and multiple criteria.  The following is kind of the structure I am going for in regards to the flags I want to set:

```
select a.*, b.WINNERID,
   case when (QUERY 1) then 1
        when (QUERY 2) then 2
        when (QUERY 3) then 3
        when (QUERY 4) then 4
        else  5 
   end as priority
from   MYTABLE  a 
left outer join MYSECONDTABLE b
on a.ID = b.ID
order by GROUP_ID, priority;
```

What I would lIke to do now is to use the following queries as what my cases should be.  The queries are not necessarily looking at the same attributes; We are looking at multiple attributes, and assigning each one an importance.

Query 1 is of the highest importance to us, Query 4 is lowest.

What I would like to do, is basically filter down the data set based on level of importance.  So lets say our dataset is 100 records; if case 1 resolves 30, then the query for case 2 should only look at the remaining 70.  the 30 resolved in case 1 would get a priority of 1 as a separate field.

**Query 1**

```
select b.WINNERID, a.*
from MYTABLE a
join MYSECONDTABLE b
on a.ID=b.ID
where WINNERID is not null;
```

**Query 2**

```
select GROUP_ID, ID from MYTABLE where COLUMN1 = 'Y' and GROUP_ID in
(
  select tb1.GROUP_ID from MYTABLE tb1 join MYTABLE tb2 on 
    tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID
    and to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) =2 
    and tb1.COLUMN1 = 'Y' and tb2.COLUMN1 = 'N'
);
```

**Query 3**

```
select distinct GROUP_ID from MYTABLE where COLUMN1 = 'Y' and GROUP_ID in
(
  select tb1.GROUP_ID from MYTABLE tb1 join MYTABLE tb2 on 
    tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID
    and to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) =2 
    and tb1.COLUMN1 = 'Y' and tb2.COLUMN1 = 'Y'
    and tb1.ID > tb2.ID
);
```

**Query 4**

```
select tb1.GROUP_ID from MYTABLE tb1 join MYTABLE tb2 on 
  tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID
  and to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) =2 
  and tb1.LAST_THING like 'WHATEVER%' and (tb2.LAST_THING not like WHATEVER%' or tb2.LAST_THING is null);
```

I would like to set a flag for each of these queries while showing the complete records .  How can I go about combining these?  Is it possible to do so?  Is there another way I should be trying to go about this?

EDIT:

Basically this is what I need:

If (Query 1) then flag =1, else if (Query 2) flag = 2, else if (Query 3) flag = 3, else if (Query 4) flag = 4, else flag = 0

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data, as small as possible while retaining the complications you expect may arise. The way you wrote your attempt is not possible; WHEN in a CASE statement expects a condition (true or false), and a subquery does not return a boolean value (true or false). Instead of trying to guess what you wanted to do, it is best if you tell us. Not through code, but in plain English.

Comment: Basically this is what I need: 

If (Query 1) then flag =1, else if (Query 2) flag = 2, else if (Query 3) flag = 3, else if (Query 4) flag = 4, else flag = 0

Comment: What does that mean? Query 1 is not true or false, so what do toy mean by if query1?

Comment: Well, query 1 is selecting records where the WINNERID field is not null.

Comment: Query 2 is looking at records within a groupid where only one of them has a column1 field as yes.  Query 3 selects for the distinct groupid where both records have a column1= y.  Query 4 wants to select for only 1 record where the string is equal to 'whatever'; if neither records are whatever, or if the attribute is null, then it's ignored.

Comment: Query1 can return 0, 1, 2 .... 1000 rows as a result, so the condition `if(query1) then 1 else 0` is ambiguous. When the condition should evaluate to tue or false? False - if the query returns 0 rows, and true if more than  rows ? Or maybe true when the query returns more than 100 rows ? True if a count of the resultset is even, and false if it is odd, perhaps ? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use queries in a CASE statement as you've shown because a query does not return a return value. You can't compare anything to `QUERY1`, for example, because `QUERY1` isn't something you can use in an expression.

Perhaps one way to do what you're trying to do would be to use your queries as common table expressions and cross join them into the main query, as in:

```
WITH QUERY1 AS (select b.WINNERID,
                       a.*
                  from MYTABLE a
                  join MYSECONDTABLE b
                    on a.ID=b.ID
                  where WINNERID is not null),
     QUERY2 AS (select GROUP_ID, ID
                  from MYTABLE
                  where COLUMN1 = 'Y' AND
                        GROUP_ID IN(select tb1.GROUP_ID
                                      from MYTABLE tb1
                                      join MYTABLE tb2
                                        on tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID AND
                                            to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) = 2 AND
                                            tb1.COLUMN1 = 'Y' AND
                                            tb2.COLUMN1 = 'N')),
     QUERY3 AS (select distinct GROUP_ID
                  from MYTABLE
                  where COLUMN1 = 'Y' AND
                        GROUP_ID IN (select tb1.GROUP_ID
                                       from MYTABLE tb1
                                       join MYTABLE tb2
                                         ON tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID AND
                                            to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) = 2 AND
                                            tb1.COLUMN1 = 'Y' and tb2.COLUMN1 = 'Y' AND
                                            tb1.ID > tb2.ID)),
     QUERY4 AS (select tb1.GROUP_ID
                  from MYTABLE tb1
                  join MYTABLE tb2
                    on tb1.GROUP_ID = tb2.GROUP_ID AND
                       to_number(substr(tb1.GROUP_ID,10,3)) = 2 AND
                       tb1.LAST_THING like 'WHATEVER%' AND
                       (tb2.LAST_THING not like 'WHATEVER%' or tb2.LAST_THING is null))
select a.*,
       b.WINNERID,
       case when q1.WINNERID > 0 then 1
            when q2.GROUP_ID > 0 then 2
            when q3.GROUP_ID > 0 then 3
            when q4.GROUP_ID > 0 then 4
            else 5 
       end as priority
  from MYTABLE  a 
  left outer join MYSECONDTABLE b
    on a.ID = b.ID
  CROSS JOIN QUERY1 q1
  CROSS JOIN QUERY2 q2
  CROSS JOIN QUERY3 q3
  CROSS JOIN QUERY4 q4
  order by GROUP_ID, priority
```

Take this as example code. I don't know what the actual conditions are you wish to check in the `CASE` statement so you'll need to make the appropriate changes.

Best of luck.

Comment: A query CAN return a value (those are called "scalar queries") and a query CAN be used in the WHEN part of a CASE expression (for example, `WHEN (select count(*) from .... ) != 0 THEN ...`, so that part of the answer is incorrect. The problem with what the OP showed is not that; it's that he wants the query to return a BOOLEAN value, and that is not possible.

Comment: @mathguy, unless you wrap it with EXISTS e.g. `case when exists (select ... from ...) then 1 else 2 end`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Right, but `exists (select...)` is not a query.

Comment: @mathguy, potato, potahto. It does answers the OP needs. P.s. Oracle limitation. PostgreSQL has no problems with queries returning booleans  `select case when (select false) then 1 else 0 end`